# SPA hosting on IIS creating issues of routing

Tags: angularjs, iis, single-page-application

I have hosted my AngularJS application on IIS.

But while browsing the url it comes out as `http://localhost/MyApp#/login`
it should be `http://localhost/MyApp/#/login`

1. Why there is difference ?
2. How to resolve the same ?

Similarly the links on the pages also showing wrong urls.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/#/MyPage1">My Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#/MyPage2">My Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#/MyPage3">My Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on any link makes URL `http://localhost/#/MyPage1` but it should be `http://localhost/MyApp/#/MyPage1`

Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<base url="" />` tag, [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

```
<head>
<base href="http://localhost/MyApp/">
</head>
```